# /undefined appearing lots of time in my 404 error log

Tags: javascript

Basically in my error log i see lots of:

```
mysite.com/undefined (with referer coming from random pages of the website)

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
```

(and some other user agent)

I have of course checked HTML or DOM for links with `/undefined` or something like that and there is just nothing. I have checked network tab with developer tools and on those page nothing requests `/undefined` (with my chrome).

I have then setted a [javascript logger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11168326/496223) to save any error that come up. And in the log there isn't nothing that throws undefined or something like that...

This is driving me crazy. Of course if i go on tihs page with my chrome, javascript doesn't print any error

Notice: i have read everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017609/undefined-randomly-appended-in-1-of-requested-urls-on-my-website-since-12-jun)

### Edit

Notice2: Beside that javascript error logger I have added an eventlistener (as explained in the answer linked)

```
$("body").on("click", "a[href$='undefined']", function() {
    window.onerror('Bad link: ' + $(this).html()); //alert home base
});
```

And this never get triggered. (I have tested it with a manual /undefined link and the logger works)

Also I found [this topic](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc) on google groups. Webmaster there are experiencing the same problem but no one has managed to nail down to the cause.

Maybe it's some **extension** on chrome or any other browser that causes this requests.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: Can you use an unminified version of the page for testing?

Comment: The real problem is that i don't see in the javascript error the page that is one referer of that 404 =/

Comment: You appear to have an `<input>` with `id=""` - the one on the left. It may not be interfering with your javascript, but why take the chance? ;)

Comment: Also, it would be tidier to refactor the javscript into a function. I assume you're testing for the input field not being empty, in which case it could be safer to use a method like that shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588229/how-to-check-if-form-input-has-value

Comment: You might want to run those pages through http://validator.w3.org/ - there are a couple of errors you may want to correct.

Comment: I have fixed the empty id="" and of course the error isn't gone. I have removed the minifing option so you can see the HTML more easly now. Anyway i suspect the cause is some external plugin, i have found this interesting discs http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc

Comment: That doesn't look like a bad HTML link, but more likely some bad JS code that changes the address using something like `window.location = somevalue`. I can't find such a usecase on goo.gl/1FJLV but I did notice a few possible causes: elements with the `linkCtrlIntercept` or `screenThumbLink` class but without a `href`, or the `lnk` javascript function called without an argument.

Comment: The Problem is on that page i dont use such link... That refere is js-free... i am start to thinking it could be some Plugin bug of the browser

Comment: There are at least 3 JavaScrtips loaded on the page. And at least the navigation scripft does lots of URL voodoo.

Comment: What webserver are you using? What is your 404 error page configured as?

Comment: Apache 2 and i have a custom 404 php  error logger setted with htacces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take another look at that Google Group thread you linked to. Just recently one of the members [managed to figure a way to disable the plugin/malware](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc/pmuCFDrSFxsJ) that appears to be causing the errors:

> To disable the malware and stop "undefiend" requests, apply this to
>   every page with a search field on your site:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>      window.suggestmeyes_loaded = true;
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you are using `window.onerror` and logging an error in that function.

If a javascript error happens on a different domain (e.g. from some social buttons, an iframe, a cross-domain javascript, or possibly a browser extension), window.onerror could actually betray sensitive information in the error report.  So for security reasons, cross-domain errors will still call the function, but all the parameters (including the url) will be undefined, and the message will just be a generic "Script error."  I would guess you are having cross domain errors, and they're being logged as undefined.

Comment: Looks like that's your issue then! FYI I typically ignore these errors, they're probably not in your code/not your fault. You can probably safely just filter them all out.

Comment: the thing is i just use adsense,google analytics e statcounter.. as external js... i don't think they can cause so many undefined

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is most likely  an ajax request using `"/" + variable` and `variable` happens to be undefined instead of say `user`.  Are you using a library for your AJAX calls? perhaps you could try to catch the invalid url in there as well.